# Converting image path to Zend_PDF_Image object

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, zend-framework

I have an issue where running the following function is returning the error report:

```
 "Cannot create image resource. File not found.";i:1;s:2101:"#0 /var/www/html/jack-london/lib/Zend/Pdf/Image.php(124): Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory::factory('http://127.0.0....')
```

Here is my code:

```
$imgPath = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_pdf/firegento_pdf/factoryx_logo_image');
$logo = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . "logo/" . $imgPath;
```

Which is returning me the correct image path:

```
http://127.0.0.1/media/logo/default/cat.jpg
```

If I paste it into my browser, the image loads as expected.

Here is my attempt to convert the path into a Zend Image Object:

```
$logo = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($logo);
```

This is the place in my code where my error report gets generated. I have tried adding quotations around the $logo variable like so:

```
$logo = "\"" . $logo . "\"";
```

But it didn't help at all. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this pretty quickly..

This path: http://127.0.0.1/media/logo/default/cat.jpg

Was not what was needed for the function, it needed this instead:

media/logo/default/cat.jpg

Hope this can help someone

Comment: Jack how you do it ? my path is /pub/media/custom_options/quote/m/y/ouekzgkdFO60ZeHs2djEIGNalvMaPfK9

and i concatenate '.png'  extension then it give error file not found even file eixst